# Assignment Problem - Students and teachers

Tags: optimization, binary-variable, assignment-problem, pulp, penalty-based-optimization

I ran across this problem at work and I'm sure that we can optimize it with OR.

---

I have $n(T) = 4$ teachers and $n(S) = 7$ students that should have a weekly individual class.

If a student $s$ has a class with teacher $t$, ideally $s$ only will have a class with $t$ after he had classes with all other teachers.

Our **constraint** is that a student cannot have classes with a teacher before he has $2$ classes with other teachers. We do that so the student's schedule is not too repetitive.

We know each student's schedule history:

```py
# Constants
teachers = ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"]
students = ["s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7"]

# Past sessions
classes_data = {
    "s1": ["t1", "t4", "t3", "t1"],
    "s2": ["t3", "t2", "t4"],
    "s4": ["t1", "t4", "t3", "t2", "t4"],
    "s6": ["t3", "t4", "t1", "t2"],
    "s7": ["t2", "t1", "t3"],
    "s5": ["t1", "t3"],
    "s3": ["t4"],
}
```

Our **objective** is to arrange the schedule for the next week minimizing the concentration of the classes on the hands of one teacher each week.

In other words, we want an even distribution of students by teachers.

---

I figured that it is an **assignment problem** where we should **minimize the variance** of the distribution of classes by teachers each week.

I am new to OR and I'm using the PuLP library. Can you guys give me advice to solve that problem?

[Here](https://pastebin.com/BgAcvHJ8) is my current attempt.

Comment: Do students need to see all teachers and if not, where do you define which teachers the students need to see? Also, what is classes_data, since you do not use that in your code?

Comment: Hint: your decision variables should be indexed by student, teacher, *and week*.

Comment: @PeterD ideally each student will have an equal number of classes with all teachers on their schedule history, as said in: *if a student s has a class with teacher t, ideally s only will have a class with t after he had classes with all other teachers.*
I could add a penalty for skipping a teacher, but I don't know how would I estimate a value for that penalty.

Comment: The `classes_data` variable stores the history of sessions that each student already had. For instance, `"s7": ["t2", "t1", "t3"]` indicates that `s7` had a class with teacher `t2` 3 weeks ago, then had a class with `t1` 2 weeks ago, and with `t3` last week. Now I need to attribute what would be his teacher this week. Ideally it should be `t4`, but without compromising the overall distribution as stated above.

Comment: The problem is infeasible. For student 3, they could never be given a class with _any_ teacher, because they have never had at least two classes with any teacher.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I should have been more specific about that constraint. The concept is that, if the student had fewer than 2 classes, as in `"s3": ["t4"]`, he can have classes with t1, t2 or t3.

Comment: Perhaps what you're actually looking for, instead of a constraint, is a secondary objective that penalizes student-teacher pairs that have more history. This would provide for a more even distribution than your current construction and would also be simpler to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comments: as it stands, the problem is infeasible. For student 3, they could never be given a class with any teacher, because they have never had at least two classes with any teacher. You need an escape hatch for students that have a small class history.

A crude approximation to "variance" that I demonstrate below is: teachers with low load are not themselves a problem, but teachers with high above-mean load variance should have their load minimized in aggregate (this accomplishes, very roughly, the same thing).

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp

teachers = ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"]
students = ["s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7"]

class_history_data = {
    "s1": ["t1", "t4", "t3", "t1"],
    "s2": ["t3", "t2", "t4"],
    "s4": ["t1", "t4", "t3", "t2", "t4"],
    "s6": ["t3", "t4", "t1", "t2"],
    "s7": ["t2", "t1", "t3"],
    "s5": ["t1", "t3"],
    "s3": ["t4"],
}

# 22 long, for every teacher-student history pair
class_history = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [student, teacher]
        for student, teachers in class_history_data.items()
        for teacher in teachers
    ],
    columns=['student', 'teacher'],
)

# 20-long, teacher-student history pair counts, multi-indexed
class_history['n'] = 1
class_history = (
    class_history.set_index(['student', 'teacher'])
    .groupby(level=['student', 'teacher'])
    .sum()
)

# 28-long: for every possible teacher-student pair
combos = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((students, teachers), names=('student', 'teacher'))
)

# 28-long names by student and teacher, e.g. s1_t2
var_names = (
    combos.index.get_level_values('student')
    + '_'
    + combos.index.get_level_values('teacher')
).to_series(index=combos.index)

combos['asn'] = var_names.apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
combos['history'] = class_history.n
combos['history'] = combos.history.fillna(value=0).astype(int)

# for a student, concerning their current potential teacher, and all other teachers
history_pairs = np.count_nonzero(
    np.broadcast_to(
        # 7x4x1
        combos.history.unstack(level='teacher').values[..., np.newaxis],
        # to 7x4x4 repeated
        (len(students), len(teachers), len(teachers)),
    )
    # with self references (teacher to same teacher) removed
    *(1 - np.eye(len(teachers))),
    axis=1,
)
# for this student-teacher pair, the number of other teachers taught at least once
combos['history_other'] = history_pairs.ravel()

# for each student, total number of classes so far
combos['history_total'] = combos.history.groupby(level='student').transform('sum')

# A student cannot have classes with a teacher before they have at least 2 classes with other teachers
# OR IF they have not yet taken classes with at least two teachers
# Express this by row elimination and not an LP constraint
# Reduces this from 28 to 26 rows.
combos = combos[
    (combos.history_other >= 2) |
    (combos.history_total < 2)
]

# 4x7, with zeros where there can never be a teacher-student assignment
assignments_by_teacher = combos.asn.unstack(level='student').fillna(0)

# 4-long: deviation above mean load per teacher (deviation below mean load is ignored).
mean_load = len(students) / len(teachers)
load_dev = (
    (
        'load_dev_' +
        assignments_by_teacher.index
        .to_series(index=assignments_by_teacher.index)
    )
    .apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0)
)

# minimize total deviation above mean load
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='class_distribution', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
prob.objective = load_dev.sum()

# Every student must have one class
for student, group in combos.asn.groupby(level='student'):
    prob.addConstraint(name=student + '_class_count', constraint=group.sum() == 1)

# The deviation above mean load has a lower bound of sum(load) - mean(load)
for teacher, load in assignments_by_teacher.sum(axis=1).items():
    prob.addConstraint(
        name='dev_' + teacher,
        constraint=load_dev[teacher] >= load - mean_load,
    )

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

print('Student-teacher assignments for this week:')
combos['asn'] = combos.asn.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value).astype(int)
print(combos.asn.unstack(level='teacher', fill_value=0), end='\n\n')

print('Teacher loads:')
loads = pd.DataFrame({
    'load': assignments_by_teacher.sum(axis=1).apply(pulp.LpAffineExpression.value),
    'deviation above mean': load_dev.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value),
})
print(loads)
```

```
class_distribution:
MINIMIZE
1*load_dev_t1 + 1*load_dev_t2 + 1*load_dev_t3 + 1*load_dev_t4 + 0
SUBJECT TO
s1_class_count: s1_t1 + s1_t2 + s1_t3 + s1_t4 = 1

s2_class_count: s2_t1 + s2_t2 + s2_t3 + s2_t4 = 1

s3_class_count: s3_t1 + s3_t2 + s3_t3 + s3_t4 = 1

s4_class_count: s4_t1 + s4_t2 + s4_t3 + s4_t4 = 1

s5_class_count: s5_t2 + s5_t4 = 1

s6_class_count: s6_t1 + s6_t2 + s6_t3 + s6_t4 = 1

s7_class_count: s7_t1 + s7_t2 + s7_t3 + s7_t4 = 1

dev_t1: load_dev_t1 - s1_t1 - s2_t1 - s3_t1 - s4_t1 - s6_t1 - s7_t1 >= -1.75

dev_t2: load_dev_t2 - s1_t2 - s2_t2 - s3_t2 - s4_t2 - s5_t2 - s6_t2 - s7_t2
 >= -1.75

dev_t3: load_dev_t3 - s1_t3 - s2_t3 - s3_t3 - s4_t3 - s6_t3 - s7_t3 >= -1.75

dev_t4: load_dev_t4 - s1_t4 - s2_t4 - s3_t4 - s4_t4 - s5_t4 - s6_t4 - s7_t4
 >= -1.75

VARIABLES
load_dev_t1 Continuous
load_dev_t2 Continuous
load_dev_t3 Continuous
load_dev_t4 Continuous
0 <= s1_t1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s1_t2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s1_t3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s1_t4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s2_t1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s2_t2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s2_t3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s2_t4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s3_t1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s3_t2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s3_t3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s3_t4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s4_t1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s4_t2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s4_t3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s4_t4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s5_t2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s5_t4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s6_t1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s6_t2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s6_t3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s6_t4 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s7_t1 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s7_t2 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s7_t3 <= 1 Integer
0 <= s7_t4 <= 1 Integer

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 16 COLUMNS
At line 129 RHS
At line 141 BOUNDS
At line 168 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 11 rows, 30 columns and 56 elements

...

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                0.75000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.02
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.02

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.02   (Wallclock seconds):       0.02

Student-teacher assignments for this week:
teacher  t1  t2  t3  t4
student                
s1        1   0   0   0
s2        0   1   0   0
s3        1   0   0   0
s4        0   0   1   0
s5        0   1   0   0
s6        0   0   1   0
s7        0   0   0   1

Teacher loads:
         load  deviation above mean
teacher                            
t1        2.0                  0.25
t2        2.0                  0.25
t3        2.0                  0.25
t4        1.0                  0.00
```

### History penalty instead of history constraint

This does better, and is also simpler:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pulp

teachers = pd.Index(name='teacher', data=("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"))
students = pd.Index(name='student', data=("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7"))

class_history_data = {
    "s1": ["t1", "t4", "t3", "t1"],
    "s2": ["t3", "t2", "t4"],
    "s3": ["t4"],
    "s4": ["t1", "t4", "t3", "t2", "t4"],
    "s5": ["t1", "t3"],
    "s6": ["t3", "t4", "t1", "t2"],
    "s7": ["t2", "t1", "t3"],
}

# 22 long, for every teacher-student history pair
class_history = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [student, teacher]
        for student, teachers in class_history_data.items()
        for teacher in teachers
    ],
    columns=['student', 'teacher'],
)

# 20-long, teacher-student history pair counts, multi-indexed
class_history['n'] = 1
class_history = (
    class_history.set_index(['student', 'teacher'])
    .groupby(level=['student', 'teacher'])
    .sum()
)

# 28-long: for every possible teacher-student pair
combos = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((students, teachers))
)

# 28-long names by student and teacher, e.g. s1_t2
var_names = (
    combos.index.get_level_values('student')
    + '_'
    + combos.index.get_level_values('teacher')
).to_series(index=combos.index)

combos['asn'] = var_names.apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpBinary)
combos['history'] = class_history.n
combos['history'] = combos.history.fillna(value=0).astype(int)

# 4-long: deviation above mean load per teacher (deviation below mean load is ignored).
mean_load = len(students) / len(teachers)
load_dev = (
    (
        'load_dev_' +
        teachers.astype(str)
        .to_series(index=teachers)
    )
    .apply(pulp.LpVariable, cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0)
)

# minimize total deviation above mean load, and minimize prior history
load_weight = 0.75
hist_weight = 1.00
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='class_distribution', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
prob.objective = load_weight*load_dev.sum() + hist_weight*combos.asn.dot(combos.history)

# Every student must have one class
for student, group in combos.asn.groupby(level='student'):
    prob.addConstraint(name=student + '_class_count', constraint=group.sum() == 1)

# The deviation above mean load has a lower bound of sum(load) - mean(load)
for teacher, load in combos.asn.groupby('teacher').sum().items():
    prob.addConstraint(
        name='dev_' + teacher,
        constraint=load_dev.loc[teacher] >= load - mean_load,
    )

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

print('Student-teacher assignments for this week:')
combos['asn'] = combos.asn.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value).astype(int)
print(combos.asn.unstack(level='teacher', fill_value=0), end='\n\n')

print('Teacher loads:')
loads = pd.DataFrame({
    'load': combos.asn.groupby('teacher').sum(),
    'deviation above mean': load_dev.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value),
})
print(loads)
```

```
Student-teacher assignments for this week:
teacher  t1  t2  t3  t4
student                
s1        0   1   0   0
s2        1   0   0   0
s3        0   0   1   0
s4        1   0   0   0
s5        0   0   0   1
s6        0   1   0   0
s7        0   0   0   1

Teacher loads:
         load  deviation above mean
teacher                            
t1          2                  0.25
t2          2                  0.25
t3          1                  0.00
t4          2                  0.25
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, @Reinderien! How could we penalize both above-average load for the teachers and teacher repetitions for each student?

For instance, if we had `teachers = [t1, t2, t3]`, `students = [s1, s2]` and `class_history_data = {s2: [t1], s2: [t1]}`

The script assigns classes to `t1` and `t3` even if `s1` and `s2` had classes with `t1`.

Between giving one extra class to a teacher and repeating a student-teacher pair, it is better to increase the teacher's load.

Comment: @nickh see edit. This form makes more sense to me I think.

Comment: Awesome @Reinderien, thank you! Definitely more elegant.